# Google Cloud Build on private VPC network

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-networking

I have a Google Cloud Build trigger that build my image on the Google Cloud. I also have VPC network that hosting some resources that should be accessible while building the images.

While building the image, my docker script need to access the web server. It seems like the GCP Cloud build network is not my private VPC network. So, the script is not accessible to required resources that needed while building.

Is this possible to run the build in the VPC network? If yes, how?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/private-pools/use-in-private-network#vpc

This is supposed to work but I haven’t used it yet

Answer (score 4):

It WILL be possible. Today, the feature is opened to Alpha testers and will be soon (I expect by 2 months) released in beta.

Last week, gcloud SDK received [this update](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/builds/worker-pools/create) that allow you to create a worker pool. In fact, you will create a pool of VM in your project. And thus, the VM will be directly connected to your VPC.

I don't know the pricing model, but I think you will pay the Worker pool as standard VM price. Therefore, it won't as cheaper as Cloud Build. And it seems not planned to create a connector (peering? VPC connector?) between your VPC and the current Cloud Build managed version.

Comment: do you have any update on the subject? I'm really interested. All I found is this old issue, which implies it isn't implemented yet: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/123374893

Comment: No update on that. Cloud Build Worker pool are still in private preview and I haven't news about Cloud Build and VPC connexion.